# Spark - Dataframe with HashSet

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is it possible to get dataframe with column of struct type supporting `scala.collection.mutable.HashSet[Int]` instead of `array<int>`?

I managed to do it with RDD.

Edit: Spark 2.0.0
immutable.HashSet[Int] -
`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type scala.collection.immutable.HashSet[Int] is not supported`

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you mutate your rows all bets are off. They're supposed to be immutable

Comment: Yah I see, not compatible with DF design. I want it to be able to use HashSets in UDF (don't wanna hash it in the UDF).

Comment: Aah now I read again what you said. So with immutable.HashSet it'd work?

Comment: No idea, I just was pointing out you don't want mutable ones

Comment: tried scala.collection.immutable.HashSet, spark 2.0.0 - no luck - java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type scala.collection.immutable.HashSet is not supported